# Limit window size when maximizing in Xfce

Tags: xfce

I have a window that is marked 'always on top'.  I want to be able to maximize another window and it have not hide behind the always on top window.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for the [desktop margins setting](http://wiki.xfce.org/tips#use_the_desktop_margin).  For example, I set a margin<sup>1</sup> so that my [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) is always visible and not covered by maximized windows.  You could do the same as long as you always place your always-on-top along the edge of the screen.

<sup>1 I don't actually use xfwm but the margin concept is the same.</sup>

Comment: Ah, yes.  It's called workspace margins in Xfce, but the same idea.  
I had thought that setting wouldn't allow the 'always on top' window to be over in the margin either.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!